# Access Sharepoint List from a Sharepoint hosted app

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I am trying to access a list from a SharePoint hosted app.

I am following instructions in this article:

[How to: Access SharePoint 2013 data from apps using the cross-domain library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179927.aspx)

According to the article, to access the list, I should use :

```
 appweburl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('My List')/items"
```

I would say that I should use hostweburl instead as the list is hosted in My SharePoint site.
Indeed, with **appweburl** I get a 404 error.

Anyway, using hostweburl doesn't solve.
The  function errorHandler return a message that the web app wasn't ditributed for this url.

Have you got any ideas or could you clarify which is the correct url to use?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179927(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: Code above is perfectly working.
I am experiencing issues with 'External List'like Gyonder. Any ideas on how can we access External list in hostweb from SharePoint hosted app using REST?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `SP.AppContextSite(@target)` to make the REST Url in order to access hostweb list:

Here is an example:

```
function getHostWebListsUsingREST() {
    var executor;

    // although we're fetching data from the host web, SP.RequestExecutor gets initialized with the app web URL..
    executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);
    executor.executeAsync(
        {
            url:
                appweburl +
                "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/?@target='" + hostweburl + "'",
            method: "GET",
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
            success: onGetHostWebListsUsingRESTSuccess,
            error: onGetHostWebListsUsingRESTFail
        }
    );
}
```

See this for more info:
http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2012/11/access-end-user-data-in-host-web-from.html

Comment: with your url the request is successful. The thing is that I want to access a specific list. And I am unauthorized to access my url list (a popup from the host asks username and password): var url = appweburl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)" +
        "/web/lists/getbytitle('MY LIST')/items?" +
        "@target='" + hostweburl + "'";

Comment: The app needs to be given access to host web. This can be done in App Mainifest file.

Comment: The app has the List permission in AppManifest. Or is it something else I should grant?

Comment: If you are simply reading from a List then having read permissions on List is enough.

Comment: I see that the problem is only with my list. With other list I've no problems. The thing about my list is that it come from an External Content Type. Maybe I should grant further permission to my app or the list?I've tried adding BCS permission to AppManifest but it still doesn't work.

Comment: I'm getting the same 401 unauthorized even though I've given 'Everyone' Full Control to the list. How do I get around this authentication?

Answer (score 1):

If you are in an app you can use the following

use this code to get hostweburl and appweb url

```
var hostweburl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl"));
var appweburl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPAppWebUrl"));

function getQueryStringParameter(paramName) {
    var params = document.URL.split("?")[1].split("&");

    for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i = i + 1) {
        var singleParam = params[i].split("=");

        if (singleParam[0] === paramName) {
            return singleParam[1];
        }
    }
}
```

this is the query to get the list

```
$.ajax({
        url: appweburl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/getbytitle('ListName')?@target='" + hostweburl + "'",
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {  
        },
        error: function (data) {
        }
});
```

Comment: Request goes successfully, but the data array is empty

Answer (score 0):

You can use also _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl to get the Url and $.ajax:

```
var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/" +
        "getByTitle('YourTitle')/items/";
    var requestHeaders = { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" };
    $.ajax({
        url: requestUri,
        async: false,
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        headers: requestHeaders,
        success: function (data) {
            //manage data.d.results
        },
        error: function (msg) {
            alert(msg.responseText);
        }
    });
```